# When should we clear Core Data cache entity?

Tags: swift, caching, core-data

I am using code in tutorial by http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift

In that tutorial the code is caching every single request.

**My question is when and how can I clear entity of caching (Core data)? Or We dont need to clear caching entity?**

Caching entity is entity where I save all data requested by NSConnection. If we need to clear cache in core data how can I choose some data to stay and others to be deleted.

For example , I am making news app. Every VC has label such as title, date, category and UIWebView.  And when app is closed I want to delete all caching links except "saved news". "Saved news" is category which users choose by tapping button "plus".

I am thinking to create new column named "isToSave". So, when user taps button to save. I need to parse content text and pull out links (src=) and in CoreData set the column "isToSave "to true. When app is closed I will delete all links with column "isTosave" = false

So shortly: is it good practice to clear entity "cacheURls" and if yes how can I clear urls by selection ?

Here is code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var requestCount = 0


class MyURLProtocol: NSURLProtocol {

    var connection: NSURLConnection!
    var mutableData: NSMutableData!
    var response: NSURLResponse!

    override class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
        println("Request #\(requestCount++): URL = \(request.URL.absoluteString)")

        if NSURLProtocol.propertyForKey("MyURLProtocolHandledKey", inRequest: request) != nil {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    override class func canonicalRequestForRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NSURLRequest {
        return request
    }

    override class func requestIsCacheEquivalent(aRequest: NSURLRequest,
        toRequest bRequest: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
            return super.requestIsCacheEquivalent(aRequest, toRequest:bRequest)
    }

    override func startLoading() {


        // 1
        let possibleCachedResponse = self.cachedResponseForCurrentRequest()
        if let cachedResponse = possibleCachedResponse {
            println("Serving response from cache")

            // 2
            let data = cachedResponse.valueForKey("data") as NSData!
            let mimeType = cachedResponse.valueForKey("mimeType") as String!
            let encoding = cachedResponse.valueForKey("encoding") as String!

            // 3
            let response = NSURLResponse(URL: self.request.URL, MIMEType: mimeType, expectedContentLength: data.length, textEncodingName: encoding)

            // 4
            self.client!.URLProtocol(self, didReceiveResponse: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .NotAllowed)
            self.client!.URLProtocol(self, didLoadData: data)
            self.client!.URLProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
        } else {
            // 5
            println("Serving response from NSURLConnection")

            var newRequest = self.request.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest
            NSURLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "MyURLProtocolHandledKey", inRequest: newRequest)
            self.connection = NSURLConnection(request: newRequest, delegate: self)
        }


    }

    override func stopLoading() {
        if self.connection != nil {
            self.connection.cancel()
        }
        self.connection = nil
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        self.client!.URLProtocol(self, didReceiveResponse: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .NotAllowed)
        self.response = response
        self.mutableData = NSMutableData()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        self.client!.URLProtocol(self, didLoadData: data)
        self.mutableData.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        self.client!.URLProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
        self.saveCachedResponse()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        self.client!.URLProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
    }


    func saveCachedResponse () {
        println("Saving cached response")

        // 1
        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context = delegate.managedObjectContext!

        // 2
        let cachedResponse = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CachedURLResponse", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        cachedResponse.setValue(self.mutableData, forKey: "data")
        cachedResponse.setValue(self.request.URL.absoluteString, forKey: "url")
        cachedResponse.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timestamp")
        cachedResponse.setValue(self.response.MIMEType, forKey: "mimeType")
        cachedResponse.setValue(self.response.textEncodingName, forKey: "encoding")

        // 3
        var error: NSError?
        let success = context.save(&error)
        if !success {
            println("Could not cache the response")
        }
    }

    func cachedResponseForCurrentRequest() -> NSManagedObject? {
        // 1
        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context = delegate.managedObjectContext!

        // 2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CachedURLResponse", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // 3
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"url == %@", self.request.URL.absoluteString!)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        // 4
        var error: NSError?
        let possibleResult = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as Array<NSManagedObject>?

        // 5
        if let result = possibleResult {
            if !result.isEmpty {
                return result[0]
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```